# MySQL query usin query results from anothe page - php

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT distinct ch.employeename, ch.customername, ch.customerowner, ch.QuestionnaireName, ch.parentgroupname, 
                                ch.groupname, ch.visitdate from chestionare ch
                                inner join agenti ag on ag.idh = ch.employeeid
                                WHERE ch.visitdate >= '$from' AND ch.visitdate <= '$to' AND
                                ch.employeename like '$agenti' AND ch.customerowner like '$clienti' AND
                                ch.class like '$task' AND ch.parentgroupname like '$categorie'
                                and ag.tipagent = 'IKA'                                 
                                ") 
                                or die(mysql_error());
```

and i display the results like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){ ?>

            <tr>
                <td> <!-- /employeename/ -->
                    <?php echo '<a href="g_angajat.php?name='.$results['employeename'].'&from='.$from.'&to='.$to.'&clienti='.$client.'&task='.$task.'&categorie='.$categorie.'">' ?>
                        <?php echo $results['employeename']; ?>
                    </a>
                </td>............
```

is it possible to create another query using first query results?
ex. $results ['employeename'] = John Mark. when i click John Mark, this name has to be used in a second query from another page.

Comment: pass the value as a parameter to the next page

Comment: Query strings....look up that term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommand the use of session variable : http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions_2.htm

There's other method ( like using the url, or POST/GET Method ) that could interest you.

Have a good day.